# byte code of initialization block generated by Java compiler

Tags: java

I want to confirm how java compiler generates copies initialization block in any  constructors.
I think as follows.

case 1) if construcotor call the other overloaded constructor,
Java compiler may not generate copy of initialization block.

case 2) if constructor doesn't the other overloaded constructor,
Java compiler may generate copy of initialization block.

Is my understanding correct?

The following document is extract of oracle tutorial.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

> Initializing Instance Members
>
> Normally, you would put code to initialize an instance variable in a
> constructor. There are two alternatives to using a constructor to
> initialize instance variables: initializer blocks and final methods.
>
> Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static
> initializer blocks, but without the static keyword:
>
> ....
>
> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.
> <<<<<<<<<<< Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of
> code between multiple constructors.　<<<<<<<<<<

The following is sample code.

```
public class SampleClass {
    int id = 0;
    static int seqID=1000;

    static{
        System.out.println("static initialization block: seqID="+ seqID);
    }
    {
        seqID++;
        System.out.println("initialization block: seqID=" + seqID);
    }
    public SampleClass(int id){
        System.out.println("constructor start");
        this.id = id;
        //this.id = seqID;
        System.out.println("constructor end");
    }
    public SampleClass() {
        this(seqID);
    }
    public void func() {
        System.out.println("seqID="+seqID+" this.id="+this.id);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args ) {
        SampleClass a=new SampleClass(SampleClass.seqID);
        a.func();
        SampleClass b=new SampleClass();
        b.func();
    }
}
```

==execution result==

```
static initialization block: seqID=1000
initialization block: seqID=1001
constructor start
constructor end
seqID=1001 this.id=1000
initialization block: seqID=1002
constructor start
constructor end
seqID=1002 this.id=1001
```

I investigated byte code of this sample code, and then java compiler generates copy
of initialization block in Sample(int) constructor only.
(Java compiler doesn't generate copy of initialization block in Sample() constructor.)

Comment: Yes you are right. `Compiler does not copy the initialization block in case there is an explicit constructor invoked`. The statement, `The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.` is misleading. The section, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-12.html, somewhat explains the sequence of operations on instance creation. There we can see steps 3 and 4 will be skipped if there are explicit constructor invocation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
It's worth it to me that I could confirm the behavior of java compiler.
I appreciate your good reply. I will see the above document at detail.